# How do you prevent SceneKit animations from playing immediately on load?

Tags: swift, animation, scenekit

I am loading a 3d model from a .usdz file, and by default the animation plays and loops immediately when it finishes loading:

```swift
let modelURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "model", withExtension: "usdz")!
let scene = try! SCNScene(url: modelURL, options: nil)

let view = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                 y: 0,
                                 width: 500,
                                 height: 500))

view.scene = scene


PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

I would like to prevent it from playing the animation when it loads.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a value with the `SCNSceneSource.AnimationImportPolicy` key to the options argument of the `SCNScene init(url:options:)` initializer:

```swift
let doNotPlay = SCNSceneSource.AnimationImportPolicy.doNotPlay

let scene = try! SCNScene(url: modelURL, options: nil)
                          options: [.animationImportPolicy: doNotPlay])
```

The list of `SCNSceneSource.AnimationImportPolicy` options in the documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenesource/animationimportpolicy)

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem in SCN Files and the Only Solution I have found is not to Stop the animation but to Reduce its speed to zero , like that It won't move from frame 1 and would be frozen like that till you decided to play it again later in the codes.

```
for key in node.animationKeys where node.animationPlayer(forKey: key) != nil
{
    let player = node.animationPlayer(forKey: key)
    player?.speed = 0
}
```